# Firebase Hosting + Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Having diffuclty deploying my functions as well as hosting.

The thing is, I have gotten them to work independently on seperate branches, however..when trying to integrate both hosting and my cloud functions, it seems that my cloud function does not deploy. I'm not receiving any errors in my terminal, and when I click 'functions' in the firebase console, it's the default screen as if no functions have deployed.

This is my firebase.json for hosting + functions deployment. **Hosting works here, but functions are not deploying**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/**",
        "function": "webApi"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Heres my firebase.json with functions only and no hosting

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/**",
        "function": "webApi"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

And heres my functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json')

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const _ = require('lodash')
const { getObjectValues } = require('./helper-functions.js')
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse

admin.initializeApp({
  ...,
})
const db = admin.firestore()

const app = express()
const main = express()

main.use('/api/v1', app)
main.use(bodyParser.json())
exports.webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main)

app.get('/test', (request, response) => {
  response.send('API TEST')
})

app.get('/surveys', (request, response) => {
  const surveyCollection = db.collection('/surveys')
  return (
    surveyCollection
      .get()
      // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        let surveyList = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const survey = doc.data()
          surveyList.push(survey)
        })
        response.send(surveyList)
      })
  )
})

app.get('/surveys/:survey', (request, response) => {
  const surveyId = request.params.survey
  const userAnswers = db.collection(`/surveys/${surveyId}/submissions`)
  return (
    userAnswers
      .get()
      // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        let surveySubmissions = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const userSubmission = doc.data()
          surveySubmissions.push({
            ..._.mapValues(userSubmission.answers, getObjectValues), // format answers
            ...userSubmission.anonUser,
          })
        })
        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=cna.json')
        response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        response.status(200).send(surveySubmissions)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  )
})
```

**Hosting + functions branch, I type 'firebase deploy'**

```
terminal output:

    i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint \surveyplus-cna\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (82.32 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: found 30 files in build
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function webApi(us-central1)...
+  functions[webApi(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: finalizing version...
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: version finalized
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: releasing new version...
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: release complete

+  Deploy complete!
```

**On cloud function only branch**
`firebase deploy` output

```
=== Deploying to '...'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint \surveyplus-cna\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (82.33 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: found 30 files in build
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function webApi(us-central1)...
+  functions[webApi(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: finalizing version...
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: version finalized
i  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: releasing new version...
+  hosting[surveyplus-effd5]: release complete

+  Deploy complete!
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly the steps you're taking that should deploy functions.  Copy the output of the command into the question so we can see what actually happened.  We should be able to take what you have in the question and reproduce the issue on our own.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added my terminal output

Comment: The output shows that your function is definitely deploying.  If that doesn't match what you see in the console, then contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Cloud Functions have deployed correctly, as I can call the [`/api/v1/test`](https://us-central1-surveyplus-effd5.cloudfunctions.net/webApi/api/v1/test) route directly just fine (at the time of writing).

However, in your `firebase.json` file, the order of your rewrites is incorrect as highlighted in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> **Important:** Within the `rewrites` attribute, the Hosting response will obey the rule specified by the *first* `source` *glob* that captures the requested path.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/**",
        "function": "webApi"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

So instead of sending `/api/v1/test` calls to be handled by your Cloud Function, they were incorrectly sent to your React app instead. Swapping the order should fix this.

Another note, if you intend all your calls to be formatted and parsed as JSON, you should reorder the `main.use` calls. I'd also use an [express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) instead of a complete `express()` instance.

```
const main = express(); // full express instance
const app = express.Router(); // "child" express instance

main.use(bodyParser.json()) // parse body as json, then hand over to app
main.use('/api/v1', app)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had a feeling it was something to do with `rewrites`, thanks for clearing that up. I have also made the changes you have suggested